# How much damage do Smoke's gas canisters deal?

Tags: rainbow-six-siege

Smoke's special ability is to throw gas bombs with a chemical agent inside that work like a damage dealing smoke grenade. My question is how much damage does the gas do (exact numbers) and does the damage get mitigated by armor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research and manual testing I came to the conclusion that damage is not mitigated by armor. As for damage values, it seems to vary wildly and i couldn't determine exact values. Damage ranges between 5 to 25 and doesn't appear to be affected by distance from center of explosion.